# Entity Framework 5 will not allow .SaveChanges

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5

I've upgraded to Entity Framework 5 and the .SaveChanges is no longer available.

How do we save our changes?

When ever I do a `db.SaveChanges();` it errors because .SaveChanges is not there.

```
    static bool Insert(Elevation elevation, out Elevation elevationOUT)
{
    using (var db = new StorefrontSystemEntities())
    {
        //erik@afbs.net : DA91DC34-FA29-4ABD-BCC0-D04408310E3E
        //projectID = 12
        elevationOUT = null;
        var projs = from p in db.Projects
                    where p.ID == elevation.ProjectID
                    select p;
        //
        var proj = projs.SingleOrDefault();
        if (proj == null) { return false; }
        //Elevation
        var elev = new Elevation
        {
            ID = proj.ID,
            Name = elevation.Name,
            Note = elevation.Note,
            ComponentID = elevation.CompID,
            VerCutHD = elevation.VerCutHD,
            VerCutSill = elevation.VerCutSill,
            Created = DateTime.Now
        };
        proj.Elevations.Add(elev);

        //Bays
        foreach (var bay in elevation.Bays)
        {
            var b = new Bay
            {
                Position = bay.Position,
                IsBulkhead = bay.IsBulkhead,
                Note = bay.Note,
                Size = GetClientSize(bay.Size),
                IsFixed = bay.IsFixed,
                Finish = GetClientFinish(bay.Finish),
                Siteline = GetClientSiteline(bay.Siteline, elev.ComponentID),
                VerCutHD = elevation.VerCutHD,
                VerCutSill = elevation.VerCutSill
                //
            };
            elev.Bays.Add(b);
        };
        db.SaveChanges();
        elevationOUT = elev;
        elevationOUT.IsGeneric = proj.GenericCatalogID > 0;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: First suggestion - check your references - specifically what they are targetting...

Comment: are you sure your `StorefrontSystemEntities` is derived from `DbContext` or `ObjectContext`? Also, do you have a reference to System.Data.Entity.dll?

Comment: What I've done is  moved from entity framework 4 to 5. and I'm having all kinds of trouble.

Comment: @AlumCloud.Com wasn't your context a partial and you've lost system's part while moving?